# What part of speech is "submitted" in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

In the phrase "The manuscript shall be submitted" I believe that "shall" is a an auxiliary, modal verb, and the word "be" is the main verb, bit what is the word "submitted".  Is "submitted" an adjective describing the manuscript?

Answer (score 1):

In a normal (active voice) sentence there is a subject, a verb and an object.

> John *[subject]* submits *[verb]* the manuscript *[object]*

If we don't want or need to say who is doing something, we can use [passive voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice): the object (called the *patient* in a passive-voice construction) moves to the front of the sentence, we add the verb **is** and the original verb becomes a past/passive participle. The subject (called the *agent*) can be omitted, or specified in a *by-agent* phrase.

> the manuscript is submitted
>   the manuscript is submitted by John

Your sentence is in the passive voice and **submitted** is a past participle which, in English, functions as a passive participle. As you pointed out, **shall** is an auxiliary verb, and **be** is required for the passive-voice construction and is the main verb.

Comment: Thanks! So in this context the passive participle functions as a verbular adjective?

Comment: participles are a kind of adjective, but a very specialized kind. You couldn't, for example, say "the manuscript is **good** by John".

Answer (score 1):

> *The manuscript shall be submitted.*

This is a passive clause in which "submitted" is a **verb** past participle.

Note the possibility of adding a *by-* phrase: "The manuscript shall be submitted *by the author ...*".

Answer (score -2):

It's [the **past participle** of *to submit*](http://en.bab.la/conjugation/english/submit).

[The past participle is often used like an adjective](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/past_participles.htm), as in your example.

Comment: mmm ... I think in this case *shall be submitted* is a passive, not a copulate predicate. You might equivalently write "[AUTHOR] shall submit the manuscript".

Comment: @stangdon Past participles are adjectival when they refer to a state or condition, as in: The manuscript is already submitted. This means that the manuscript has already been submitted (here "submitted" is clearly passive, as it refers to the action of having been submitted). Here's a clearer example, with a different participle: The window was broken by some vandals (here "broken" is the past participle of the passive, as it refers to the action of having been broken) BUT Now the window is broken (here "broken" is clearly adjectival, as it refers to the condition or state of destruction).